# Re-bind a jquery on click after I have ajaxed the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have three images that when you click on them brings up a larger image. A really basic gallery I made. Any way when im changing content on the page with the .load(), it doesnt register the click any more for the div.

How to I reload the jquery or reload the event handlers?

Here is what I was trying

```
function recheckTheImageClickers(){
$('#img1').on('click', function(){
    change1();
});
});
```

I tried to run this function after the ajax to see if it would re-bing the $img1 to a click function but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what's calling this recheckTheImageClickers function ?

Comment: its in the success part of the .load()

Comment: I figured it out, it wasent in the success part of the .load(). IT works now. TY!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I wasn't running the function in the success part of .load(). It works now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect spot for jQuery's `live` or `delegate` (both now deprecated in favor of using `on` with more parameters):

```
$(parentSelector).on('click', '#img1', function(){ change1(); });
```

As long as your `parentSelector` is outside of the AJAX refreshed DOM elements, and `#img1` is a child of said parent, this should work without needing to re-execute it.